# How to get ContextPath in init() method of Servlet version 2.4

Tags: java, servlets, contextpath

I'm using version 2.4 of `Servlet` and I need to get the `ContextPath` through the `init()` method  which is called on server start, so I don't have any *Request object* that could call `getContextPath()` and because the Servlet version I do not have `getContextPath()` method in the `ServletContext` either.

Is there a way to get this `ContextPath()` somehow ?

Comment: [ServletContext.getServletContextName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletContextName()) - ServletConfig.getServletContext().getServletContextName()

Comment: this is null in my case :/

Answer (score 2):

One web application can be published at several different context paths, so *the* context path (singular) is only meaningful in the context of a particular request.  Servlet 2.5 added `getContextPath()` to `ServletContext`, specified to return the "primary" context path for this web application, but there's no container-independent way to access this information in earlier spec versions.

There may be tricks that work for certain containers, for example on Tomcat the `ServletContext.getResource()` method returns URLs with a custom scheme, of the form `jndi://hostname/context/...`.  Thus you may be able to use

```
ctx.getResource("/").getPath()
```

to get the context path on Tomcat (or possibly `getResource("/WEB-INF/web.xml")` and trim off the tail, as `getResource()` is specified to return `null` if you ask it for a file that does not exist).  You will have to experiment with different containers to find similar tricks that work on those.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be only possible form servlet 2.5 as explained in this post: [ServletContext getContextPath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120860/servletcontext-getcontextpath)

Answer (score 1):

You are right in Servlet 2.4 the object ServeltContext does not have the method getContextPath.

I can suggest two options:

1. Set the context path as parameter of the servlet:

   `<servlet`>

   ```
   <servlet-name>initServlet</servlet-name>

   <servlet-class>net.cirrus-it.InitServlet`</servlet-class>

   <init-param>
           <param-name>contextPath</param-name>
           <param-value>/myApp</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```

   `</servlet`>
2. Try to determine the context path from the method getRealPath()

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)

According to the documentation:

> Returns a String containing the real path for a given virtual path.
>   For example, the path "/index.html" returns the absolute file path on
>   the server's filesystem would be served by a request for
>   "http://host/contextPath/index.html", where **contextPath** is the **context path** of this ServletContext.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
class demo extends HttpServlet {
       public void init(ServletConfig config) {
             String path = config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
       }
}
```

It should work

Comment: That will give the real filesystem path to the webapp directory (e.g. `/var/tomcat/webapps/foo`), not the context path at which the app is deployed (`/foo`).  As krampstudio says, Servlet 2.5 added `getContextPath()` to `ServletContext`, returning the "primary" context path for the application, but in 2.4 or earlier you can only get the path for a particular request.